# how to pass this structure array to the function ,whats wrong with my code?

Tags: c, arrays

**the question was:**

A course is characterized by the following:

```
Course Name: cName (string of 32 characters)
Course Number: cNumber (integer)
Number of Students enrolled: nStudents (integer)
Level: Level (character: ‘G’ for graduate, ‘U’ for undergraduate)
Grades: sGrades (array of 40 integers)

Define a structure, called CourseType, which includes the above properties.

In the main program: use the structure you defined to declare an array of 5 courses, and store in this array the information below about these courses (the information below specify the course name, number, number of students, and level:

“Introduction to Programming”, 230, 37, ‘U’
“Computer Networks”, 450, 44, ‘U’
“Data Structures & Algorithms”, 330, 38, ‘U’
“Distributed Databases”, 630, 18, ‘G’
“Mobile Ad hoc Networks”, 656, 34, ‘G’
```

Concerning the grades, for each course, generate as many random values as there are students and store them in the array of grades (sGrades). These values should be between 50 and 100.

```
Write a function DisplayCourseStatistics that takes as input a course structure, and computes the average grade, minimum grade, and maximum grade in the course. After computing these three values, the function displays them.

In the main program: after defining the structure and the five courses in part c, and populating these courses with the data (including the grades), ask the user to specify the course number. Then call the function DisplayCourseStatistics and pass it the corresponding course structure in order for it to display the grade statistics (average, minimum, and maximum).
```

**The code i wrote** i still have errors=[

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
typedef struct CourseType CourseType;
struct CourseType
{
char cName[32];
int cNumber;
int nStudents;
char Level;
int sGrades[44];
};
void DisplayCourseStatistics(CourseType course[],int n);
int main()
{
int i;
CourseType course[5];
strcpy(course[0].cName,"Introduction to Programming");
course[0].cNumber=230;
course[0].nStudents=37;
course[0].Level='U';
for(i=0;i<37;i++)
{
course[0].sGrades[i]=50+rand()%(50);
}
strcpy(course[1].cName,"Computer Networks");
course[1].cNumber=450;
course[1].nStudents=44;
course[1].Level='U';
for(i=0;i<44;i++)
{
course[1].sGrades[i]=50+rand()%(50);
}
strcpy(course[2].cName,"Data Structures & Algorithms");
course[2].cNumber=330;
course[2].nStudents=38;
course[2].Level='U';
for(i=0;i<38;i++)
{
course[2].sGrades[i]=50+rand()%(50);
}
strcpy(course[03].cName,"Distributed Databases");
course[3].cNumber=630;
course[3].nStudents=18;
course[3].Level='G';
for(i=0;i<18;i++)
{
course[3].sGrades[i]=50+rand()%(50);
}
strcpy(course[4].cName,"Mobile Ad hoc Networks");
course[4].cNumber=656;
course[4].nStudents=34;
course[4].Level='G';
for(i=0;i<34;i++)
{
course[4].sGrades[i]=50+rand()%(50);
}
int n;
printf("enter the course number that you'd like to display its stat");
scanf("%d",&n); 
DisplayCourseStatistics(CourseType course[n],n);
}
void DisplayCourseStatistics(CourseType course[n],int n)
{
int average_grade;
int minimum_grade;
int maximum_grade;
int sum=0;
int i;
for(i=0;i<course[n].nStudents;i++)   
{
sum+=course[n].sGrades[i];
if(course[n].sGrades[i]>course[n].sGrades[i+1])
{  
minimum_grade=course[n].sGrades[i+1];
maximum_grade=course[n].sGrades[i];
}
else if(course[n].sGrades[i]<course[n].sGrades[i+1])
{
minimum_grade=course[n].sGrades[i];
maximum_grade=course[n].sGrades[i+1];
}
}
printf("The Average Grade is %d\nThe Maximum Grade is %d\nThe Minimum Grade is %d\n",average_grade=(sum/course[n].nStudents),maximum_grade,minimum_grade);
```

}

whats wrong and what can i do 
thanks!!!

for the comments
it is supposed to be 40 but i'm using 44 cause in one course the number of students is 44 which is >40 so and for the errors actually i've been usinf codepad so i'm not sure it says  that **error: too few arguments to function 'DisplayCourseStatistics'**

Comment: What _specific_ problem do you have? What is working, what isn't, and what don't you understand about the errors?

Comment: What error/warning messages does the compiler give?  If none, what is the code producing on what input and what is it you expected?

Comment: Just a note: Your course characterization says "Grades: sGrades (array of 40 integers)" but you did declare it as `int sGrades[44];`. Shouldn't that be a 40?

Comment: Are you compiling C with a C++ compiler?

Comment: @DuaaAl; sorry for big re-edit here. But posted a fix first, then read the task. As you can see there are some changes.

Comment: Please post code formatted readable ... :-/

Comment: np :), If it solved your problem it is nice to get an accept :P

Answer (score 1):

Here you need to pass the stucture array same as you do in case of the array.
Consider this line:

```
DisplayCourseStatistics(CourseType course[n],n);
```

This is wrong.
You can write similiar to array, just pass the name of your struct as :

```
DisplayCourseStatistics(course,n);
```

Now you need to se the defination of your function:

```
void DisplayCourseStatistics(CourseType course[n],int n)
```

This should be as

```
void DisplayCourseStatistics(CourseType course[],int n)
```

Now conclusion, If you need to pass a structure or its array, you need to pass the pointer to that structure or pointer to fisrt member to array of structure in case of array. That's how you can pass the structure variable to a function.

Answer (score 0):

***Conforming to text***

The task is to ask for course number and display that course. As of now you are asking for the array index and displaying that. Also you are not supposed to send both index and array, only the specific course to the `DisplayCourseStatistics()` function.

As you say in the heading of the question "*how to pass this strcture array to the function […]"*; - but this breaks with the task,

You are supposed to have:

```
                                           +--- Struct, not array of struct
                                           |
void DisplayCourseStatistics(CourseType course)
{
    ...
```

In main:

```
/* You can't specify type when calling */
DisplayCourseStatistics(CourseType course[n], n);
                        \__________________/
                                 |
                                 +--- Why do you do this?

/* Becomes: */
DisplayCourseStatistics(course);
```

Then you have to change the prototype and signature of `DisplayCourseStatistics()` to conform to this; as shown above.

After you have done this you have to fix that function to not use an array.

Beside this you also have an error in the *Display*-function: You go outside the bounds of the array as you say `.sGrades[i+1]` while you at the same time makes `i` become number of items in `.sGrades[]`.

---

As a side note: it is no problem using line breaks on i.e.:

```
printf("The Average Grade is %d\n"
       "The Maximum Grade is %d\n"
       "The Minimum Grade is %d\n",
       average_grade=(sum/course[n].nStudents),
       maximum_grade,minimum_grade);
```

---

Also: You should validate `scanf()` by ensuring it returns 1 (for 1 item successfully parsed, namely "%d").

If someone enter a non integer you cannot "access" `n` as it is not initialized.

After number is successfully read you need to find a way to "translate" that number to correct course index of the `course` array, and pass that to the "calculate and print" function.

I.e.

User enters 330, you'll need to find the correct index, as of now `course[2]` and pass that one.